# How to change math symbols of the stix package to CM ones?

Tags: math-operators, stix

Well, math operators like `\int` or `\sum` provided by the `stix` package are in my opinion ugly and I want those of CM instead. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 10):

The chase starts from finding out how `\int` is defined by default: one sees that `\int` becomes `\intop\nolimits` and we want to see how `\intop` is defined.

The answer is in `fontmath.ltx`, one of the files read in at format creation; line 268 has

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"52}
```

OK, what's `largesymbols`? Line 77 has

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
```

Very well, the hunt was successful!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"52}

\begin{document}
\[
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx=\textstyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For `\sum` the hunt is a bit harder, because one should know that `stix` takes an approach similar to `amsmath`, so we have to redefine `\sumop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"50}

\begin{document}
\[
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx=\textstyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
\]
\[
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{1}{3}n\biggl(n+\frac{1}{2}\biggr)(n+1)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

After seeing the result with `\sum`, I doubt one would like to have it.

Comment: One suspects that the hunt was rigged and that you knew where the prey was hiding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Shhh!

Comment: Great job. Appreciate it. However, I like all of them changed! I tested your code with `\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"50}` and it didn't work!

Comment: @MiladO. If you want to also change `\sum`, you need `largesymbolsCM` as for `\intop`

Comment: @egreg What if i need to replace the CM sum symbol with the STIX ones? is it possible?