# How to import the summation symbol from the "STIX" font

Tags: fonts

I would like to use the summation symbol provided by `STIX` package. I did try something but nothing worked. Here is what i attempted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"B3}
\begin{document}
Hi, here is the $\sum$ and $$\sum$$ symbol of STIX
\end{document}
```

This was showing an error and didn't compile at all :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set-up the `LS2` encoding and avoid overwriting the `largesymbols`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{xlargesymbols}{"B3}

\begin{document}

Hi, here is the $\sumop$ and
\[ \sumop \]
symbol of STIX and here are the standard $\sum$ and
\[ \sum \]
symbols.
\end{document}
```

In your sample file the first error in the `.log` file is

> ```
> LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `LS2' unknown.
> ```

telling that the encoding scheme has not been defined.  Digging around the `stix.sty` file, leads to how that files sets-up the encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Yes i did see that. But where did you pick up this comand \Declarefontencoding{LS2} thing??

Comment: You should redefine `\sum@`, since you're using `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg From the code in the question it looks like he wants an extra sum symbol `\sumop`.  But that is not quite what is written in the text...

Comment: The OP was probably misled by another situation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212089/4427

Comment: @egreg Well how did you catch that :P. I exactly looked into this

Answer (score 4):

Andrew’s answer is only partial.

If you want to full substitute `\sum` with the STIX symbol, you have to redefine `\sum@`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@} 
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsSTIX}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum@}{\mathop}{largesymbolsSTIX}{"B3}
\makeatother

\begin{document}         

Hi, here is the $\sum$ and $\displaystyle\sum$ symbol of STIX

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. The `amsmath` package saves `\sum` in `\sum@` and then redefines `\sum` to be a complex macro; it does so in order to comply with the `\dots` features and to respect the `sumlimits` or `nosumlimits` options.
2. Just defining `\sumop` will not make the symbol comply with the above features.
3. The font encoding `LS2` is not known to LaTeX, so it should be declared before referring to a font using it. The required `\DeclareFontEncoding` command can be found in `stix.sty`.

Comment: Thanks for this. How do i import a single alphabet of the STIX font. Suppose i want to import just the alphabet N of STIX how do i do that? Attempted this `\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{LS1}{stix}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`N}` but this is changing all the math alphabets. :(

Comment: @S.C. You need to give a different name than `letters`, or this would override the default one.

Comment: Let me check and come back

Comment: Yahooo! Working :D

Comment: One More question. What about lbrace and rbrace. I tried to use `\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{operators}{"5E}{xlargesymbols}{"0C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{operators}{"60}{xlargesymbols}{"0D}` but this only working when things are at set at displaymath mode. If i type $\{e\}$, then braces aren't being produced. Any idea?

Comment: @S.C. The site doesn't work like this.

Comment: Are u asking me to pose a different question?